# Youtube api not playing musics on tv speakers

Tags: android, browser, youtube, youtube-api, android-browser

I am using youtube player api to play youtube videos for my application.

Have tested my application by connecting my Tab with TV by using HDMI cable.

Error :

When I run the video from my application, musics plays in **tablet speaker**

When I run the same video in youtube.com it plays in **TV speaker**

Youtube api not playing musics on tv speakers instead playing in tab speaker.

My Code :

```
this.player = new YT.Player('youtube-player', {
    height: this.videoHeight,
    width: this.videoWidth,
    videoId: videoId,
    playerVars: {
        autoplay: 1,
        controls: 0,
        fs:0,
        rel : 0
    },
    origin: this.getHostName(),
    events: {
        onReady: function () {
            // Code Goes Here
        },
        onStateChange: function (event) {
            // Code Goes Here
        },
        onError: function () {
            // Code Goes Here
        }
    }
});
```

[Docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) Which I am following.

This happens with **latest Chrome release and Chrome Beta**

Can anyone explain what would be the problem?.

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Please show some code you've written and provide a link to the docs of the youtube api you're using.

Comment: @creimers Have updated my question with my code and docs which I am following.

Comment: So you only try it with chrome? Try to use other browser and observe the results. I think this is not an issue with the Youtube API.

Answer (score 0):

After few research have found the solution. If microphone access has enabled the music will play from tab speakers instead of tv speakers.

Hope it will help for someone else also.